# Android Studio 4.2.1 LoginPage class shows red line under class name

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio and the problem i am facing is this; i have developed my app to a certain extent but i noticed that a red line appears below the name of one of my classes and also in the file structure section of android studio. I don't know what this means and don't know how to get rid of it.
I have attached a screenshot of my work environment for you all to see.

Can someone please help with a way to clear this out.

Thank you.
[the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9nLB.png)

Comment: It means there is at least one mistake in that file, you can see the exact line on the scrollbar. Also if you run that project it will won't start and tell you what lines are the problem. Same as almost every other IDE.

Comment: I agree with you @javdromero but how can i find where the error is and resolve it in android studio 4.2.1